# Windows doesn't route packets correctly to a 10. IP address if VPN also gives 10. IP addresses

Tags: networking, windows-10, routing, openvpn

Windows 10 Home, [OpenVPN client](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/downloads.html)

At a particular site, the wireless uses a 10.50.18 network with a 255.255.255.0 subnet mask (10.50.18/24).  The OpenVPN adapter I have grabs a 10.47.10 address with a 255.255.255.0 subnet mask (10.47.10/24).

If you evaluate the IP address and the subnet mask, you realize that they are two completely different networks that have nothing to do with each other.  However, if you use [classfull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classful_network) addressing (which has been deprecated for years), you would come to the conclusion that they are the same network.  10. ("ten dot") was a class A network (and nowadays [by default uses a "class A" subnet mask](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-routable_ip_address#Private_IPv4_address_spaces)) so only the first octet would have mattered in that case, even if we assign a "class C" subnet.

Windows does not let me access LAN resources while the VPN is active, presumably because of a networking conflict of some kind.  What is this conflict?  How do I work around it?  It seems that something in the networking stack is not fully evaluating the IP and subnet to determine which adapter the traffic needs to go out.

I am able to access LAN resources fine on 192.* and 172.* networks even if the VPN is active.  I can't change the IP scheme of the site with 10.50.18 addresses.

I would have liked to have posted this to the [Networking SE](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/), but this is for SOHO/prosumer application/use, so I don't think it's welcome there.

The problem above refers to "TAP-Windows Adapter V9" and "Qualcomm Atheros QCA61x4A Wireless Network Adapter".

Routing table:

```
C:\Users\Tablet>netstat -rn
===========================================================================
Interface List
 23...00 e0 4c 68 1f e2 ......Realtek USB GbE Family Controller
 17...c8 3a 35 cf 35 80 ......Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #2
 18...00 ff 9c 8f 6f 51 ......TAP-Windows Adapter V9
 22...54 8c a0 70 57 e5 ......Qualcomm Atheros QCA61x4A Wireless Network Adapter
 29...c8 3a 35 cf 35 86 ......802.11n USB Wireless LAN Card
  4...54 8c a0 70 57 e6 ......Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network)
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
  2...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft Teredo Tunneling Adapter
 12...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #8
  9...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #9
 13...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #10
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.1    192.168.1.105     50
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0       10.50.18.1     10.50.18.138     50
          0.0.0.0        128.0.0.0       10.47.10.5       10.47.10.6     35
       10.47.10.1  255.255.255.255       10.47.10.5       10.47.10.6     35
       10.47.10.4  255.255.255.252         On-link        10.47.10.6    291
       10.47.10.6  255.255.255.255         On-link        10.47.10.6    291
       10.47.10.7  255.255.255.255         On-link        10.47.10.6    291
       10.50.18.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      10.50.18.138    306
     10.50.18.138  255.255.255.255         On-link      10.50.18.138    306
     10.50.18.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      10.50.18.138    306
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        128.0.0.0        128.0.0.0       10.47.10.5       10.47.10.6     35
      192.168.1.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.1.105    306
    192.168.1.105  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.1.105    306
    192.168.1.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.1.105    306
     209.95.50.27  255.255.255.255       10.50.18.1     10.50.18.138     50
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.1.105    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      10.50.18.138    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link        10.47.10.6    291
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.1.105    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      10.50.18.138    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link        10.47.10.6    291
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None

IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
  1    331 ::1/128                  On-link
  1    331 ff00::/8                 On-link
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None

C:\Users\Tablet>
```

Comment: I'm not a networking expert, but they look like they should be on the same network to me. The network address for both is 10.50.18 and they both have the same subnet mask. Unless you made a mistake in typing, I don't see how "evaluat[ing] the IP address and subnet mask" would lead to the conclusion that they are "two completely different networks that have nothing to do with each other". To be clear, I'm genuinely confused here.

Comment: Whoops, copypasta error!

Comment: Fair enough! :)

Comment: Add the routing table to your post. You can use `route print -4` or `netstat -rn`.

Comment: What addresses are those LAN resources at?

Answer (score 1):

This is a common scenario where you use a VPN to connect to a company network while at the same time being connected to an "untrusted" local network.

In most cases the VPN client software intentionally enforces this blockade to prevent your computer becoming a bridge between the VPN network and the local LAN.

It is not a routing issue at all, but an intentional security precaution.
The VPN client in such cases firewalls the local LAN off and gives itself the lowest metric value in the routing table so it becomes the sink for all traffic.
The latter can be seen in your dump of the routes.

Comment: This doesn't make sense, or you are skipping too much in an attempt to be brief and I'm not interpolating enough.  I normally keep my interpolators over level 9000, but I'm not picking up bad interpolation.

Comment: @DanWhaley My iPhone somehow lost the last 2 lines of my answer. I have re-added them back in.

Comment: Even if the metric is changed, the networks are different.  With a completely different LAN IP scheme, things work fine.  These networks are also different, but taking into account history, you could make an argument they are similar.  I'm guessing some programmer somewhere hard coded in subnet masks or something.